# Laravel 5.2.38 font-awesome showing empty boxes

Tags: laravel-5, font-awesome

I just started studying Laravel, my app works fine and I was able to reference all my css and js files but one thing is not working correctly.. I downloaded font-awesome package from their site and install it manually on my app.. I referenced the font-awesome.min.css file on my master head file. it loads the css file but not the actual font-awesome web fonts file.. below is the folder structure inside my public folder

```
---public
  --assets
    -css
    -js
    -fonts
    -images
```

i used blade to link the font-awesome css file.. on chrome dev tools it shows that it loads the css file but not the font files.

```
 {{ Html::style('assets/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}
```

any ideas how to make it work??

Thanks guys..

Comment: Did you put the font files inside your fonts directory ?

Comment: Insetead of `Html::style()` you can use something like follows `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">`, make sure to use the correct path and the file is actually there.

Comment: Hi.. @IsmailRBOUH- yes all my fonts are inside the fonts directory..

Comment: yes.. @alariva I tried that code also but still not working.. I carefully checked my file path and all files are in their respective directories..

Comment: What are you getting rendered in the browser for both cases? please share with [pastebin](http://laravel.io/bin)

Comment: please check this pastebin http://pastebin.com/vU9pmsu8